# probability of picking phones in random to fill up a bin

Tags: probability, statistics

suppose Samsung has two phones Samsung galaxy and Samsung galaxy note in supposed infinite bins (i.e there is an infinite number of the phones) and josh wants to fill out boxes with these phones that have an equal probability of being picked. each box can hold up to 50 phones, and josh picks each phone to put it in the box one by one.

1. what is the probability that when josh fills out 2 boxes exactly one of them have 20% samsung galaxy and 80% Samsung galaxy note?
2. what is the probability that josh must fill out 9 boxes in total in order to have 5 boxes with 20% Samsung galaxy and 80% Samsung galaxy note?

for (1) I'm sure that I have to start out to find the probability of selecting 10 samsung galaxy and 40 Samsung galaxy notes but I'm not sure where to go from there

Comment: How many boxes are there?

Comment: @callculus total number of boxes? its infinite as the number of phones are infinite. But for qs 1 its asking when 2 boxes are filled and only one of them have have 20% samsung galaxy and 80% Samsung galaxy note

Comment: OK. Thanks for the response.

Comment: My idea is the same. Since these phones that have an equal probability of being picked the prob. that a Samsung galaxy phone is picked is constant $0.5$. So we can use the binomial distribution. In my opinion the prob. that the first box has 20% samsung galaxy and 80% Samsung galaxy note is $\binom{50}{40}\cdot 0.5^{40}\cdot 0.5^{10}$. Edit: I notice that InstellarProbe had the same idea.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a filled box. The probability that box has exactly the 20%/80% split is

$$\dbinom{50}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{50}$$

The probability that a filled box has a different split is:

$$1 - \dbinom{50}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{50}$$

The probability that out of two boxes, exactly one will have the prescribed split is:

$$2\left(\dbinom{50}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{50}\right)\left(1-\dbinom{50}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{50}\right)$$

For part (2), the problem is worded very strangely. I am not sure exactly what it is asking. I suspect that it is asking what is the probability that when Josh fills 8 boxes, he does not have 5 boxes with the specified split, but when he fills 9 boxes, he does? That implies that among the 8 filled boxes, four of them have the necessary split and four do not, then the ninth box does. This scenario would occur with the following probability:

Let $p = \dbinom{50}{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)^{50}$. Then, the probability is:

$$\dbinom{8}{4}p^5(1-p)^4$$

Plug in for $p$.